# How to get number occurrences of any element of an array in another array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have an array:

```
const myArray1 = [{tags: ['tag-1', 'tag-2']}, {tags: ['tag-1']}, {tags: ['tag-5', 'tag-8']}]
```

And an array2:

```
const myArray2 = [
  {
    tags: [
       "tag-122",
      "tag-1",
      "tag-2",
      "tag-12"
    ]
  },
  {
    tags: [
      "tag-1",
      "tag-10",
      "tag-12"
    ]
  },
  {
    tags: [
      "tag-5"
    ]
  }
];
```

I want to get an array

```
const resultArray = [{tags: ['tag-1', 'tag-2'], count: 2}, {tags: ['tag-1'], count: 2}, {tags: ['tag-5', 'tag-8'], count: 1}]
```

For every element in myArray1 check if any element of array tags in  myArray1 contains in myArray2. if contains, find the count of occurrences

I try to make an array of myArray2 tags and then find occurrences in array for every element of myArray1

```
const result = myArray2.reduce((acc, el) => {
  el.tags && el.tags.map(tag => acc.push(tag));
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd transform the `myArray2` into an array of Sets for reduced computational complexity, then `.map` the `array2` and check if `.some` of the tags being iterated over exists in the set, counting the number of occurrences with `reduce`:

```js
const myArray1=[{tags:["tag-1","tag-2"]},{tags:["tag-1"]},{tags:["tag-5","tag-8"]}],
      myArray2=[{tags:["tag-122","tag-1","tag-2","tag-12"]},{tags:["tag-1","tag-10","tag-12"]},{tags:["tag-5"]}];

const arr2Sets = myArray2.map(({ tags }) => new Set(tags));

const resultArray = myArray1.map(({ tags }) => {
  const count = arr2Sets.reduce(
    (a, set) => a + tags.some(tag => set.has(tag)),
    0
  );
  return { tags, count };
});
console.log(resultArray);
```